# Function for Using Now instead of GetDate in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use Now() to get current date and time, so trying to create a function, just cannot get syntax right

```
USE [db1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Now]()
RETURNS [date] AS 
BEGIN

Declare @Now1

Select GetDate()                

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Now1
END
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why? What is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: @SeanLange maybe OP is a ColdFusion developer and that's their equivalent :P  Additionally your return type of `date` does not include the time, you need a `datetime`.

Comment: I don't get what you mean about them being a ColdFusion dev. All languages deal with some things in a slightly different syntax. Creating a scalar function to return the value of a scalar function for no other reason the changing the name is silly.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, just thought *maybe* that could be a reason (although not a good one IMO).

Comment: How about using the ANSI standard CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?  This is supported by most databases and a good choice for portability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create your own function to get current date, you can use

```
 Select  GetDate()
```

just kidding :) I imagine that you want to do something more than returning only current date

Type the body this way:

```
Declare @Now1 datetime
Select  @Now1 = GetDate()
```

so your full code should  be

```
USE [db1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[Now]()
RETURNS [datetime] AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @Now1 datetime
    Select  @Now1 = GetDate()       
    RETURN @Now1
END
```

Comment: Return type should probably be `datetime` as per OPs requirements (though OP specified date in their function declaration as well)

Answer (score 1):

This seems completely ridiculous and pointless but you are making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

```
create function Now() 
returns datetime as 
begin 
    return getdate()
end

select dbo.Now()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of `@Now1` first.

```
DECLARE @Now1 DATETIME;
```

And then you need to set it.

```
SET @Now1 = GETDATE();
```